# A single product details is showing in homepage instead of homepage magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

My magento2 site was working fine. suddenly a single product details is showing in homepage instead of actual homepage.

How can i fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the url rewrites, this usually happens when a product rewrite has an empty request path.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue, navigate to Marketing>URL Rewrites and look for a request path record that is currently empty. Edit this particular record and enter a URL path in the format of "url-path-like-this" as the request path. Save the changes, and this should effectively solve the problem.